# IPv4 pattern regex is not working angular6

Tags: angular

I am trying to use IPv4 regex in an Angular 2 template form.

```
ipV4Pattern = '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$';
```

This is the regex I am trying to use.

But it is not working. Here is the [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-form-pattern-ip6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please help

Comment: Can you specify what is not working?

Comment: It is showing valid without any DOT

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. For me it is working as it is supposed to be